# Android Studio and Emulator not responding

Tags: windows, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I have an Acer Aspire E5-573 laptop with 4Gb RAM, Windows-10 64 bit operating system. Whenever I start my Android Studio, my laptop stops responding, and I am my program does not run on the emulator. What do you think would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase your RAM atleast 8gb,

alternative way:
Use lower version of android studio because version 4.0 and up has many features like animations etc. don't use AVD Android Virtual Device instead try to use Physical phone as emulator

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly happen when your computers memory (RAM) run out, when there is no sufficient memory(RAM) space left to run your program than your laptop is not responding.

Possible solution

1. Increase your RAM (memory) to minimum 8 GB and
2. Include a SSD storage in your laptop

Comment: I'll try that... Thanks a lot